# Double calls to plot/load functions in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have an app with a map, dropdown, calendar and line plot (my real app is much bigger but I have simplified as much as I can). The problem with it is that when I modify any of the uicontrol features, the data loading and plotting routines run twice (as evidenced from the print statements). In the full app the plots display a reasonable amount of data so running them twice leads to poor performance.

The app is structured so that I can select 1 of 2 predefined points on the map and it will change the dropdown and graph. A new location can also be selected with the dropdown menu (which in turn updates the map). There is also a checkbox to lock the timeframe and when this is not selected the timeframe gets reset to the extents of the timeseries for the new location.

I have isolated the problem to the updateDateRangeInput that is called in the server.R file (line 35). I can comment this out and the problem goes away, but then I lose the functionality to reset the calendar to the new timeframe. Does anyone know how I can keep that functionality but stop the data loading and plotting code from running twice?

Example app below:

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)

source('ui.R')
source('server.R')

ui <- ui_page()

server <- server_page(input, output, session)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dygraphs)

inc_level <- 5

ui_page <- function(){

  fluidPage(

    
  titlePanel("TEST APP"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      leafletOutput('region_map'),

      selectInput(inputId = "Site",label = "Pick a site",choices = c("A","B"), selected = "A"),
      
      fluidRow(
        column(6, 
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "timeframe",label="Select time range", start ="2015-07-01", end = "2016-07-01")),
      
      column(4,checkboxInput(inputId = "lock_timeframe",label = "Lock Time Range"))
      
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Plot 1", dygraphOutput(outputId = "plot1"))

      )
    )
  )
)
}
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

server_page <- function(input, output, session){

# Create Data -------------------------------------------------------------

  Y1 <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
  Time1 <- startdate <- as.Date(c('2007-11-1','2008-3-25','2010-3-14'))
  Y2 <- c(11000, 11400, 16800)
  Time2 <- startdate <- as.Date(c('2001-11-1','2003-3-25','2005-3-14'))

  Lat <-c(-39.095980, -39.605823)
  Lon <- c(173.887903, 173.824561)
  Site <- c("A","B")
  
# Extract  Data -------------------------------------------------------
  df1 <- reactive({
    print("load data")

    if (input$Site=="A"){
      df1 <- data.frame(Time1, Y1)
    }
    else if (input$Site=="B"){
      df1 <- data.frame(Time2, Y2)
    }
    names(df1) <- c("Time","Y")

    if (1){ # IF YOU CHANGE THIS TO A 0 FUNCTIONLITY IS LOST BUT PROBLEM GOES AWAY
      
      lockTest <- input$lock_timeframe
      if (lockTest==FALSE){
        updateDateRangeInput(session, "timeframe",
                             start = df1$Time[1],
                             end =df1$Time[length(df1$Time)])
      }
    }

    df1 <- df1[df1$Time >= format(input$timeframe[1]) & df1$Time <= format(input$timeframe[2]),]
    
    validate(need(nrow(df1)!=0, "No Data In Range"))
    
    return(df1)  
  }) #%>% bindCache(input$Site) # I woudl like to cache based on location to stop reloading of data from file in the full app


# Line Plot --------------------------------------------------------

  output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({
    print("Plotting")
    data <- df1()
    data <- xts(x = data$Y, order.by = data$Time)
    
    dyPlt <- dygraph(data,width = 800, height = 400)
  })

# Plot Map -----------------------------------------------------

  output$region_map <- renderLeaflet({

    y <- Lat
    x <- Lon
    id <- Site
    
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap, options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
      setView(lng = 174.051515, lat = -39.301619, zoom = 8) %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng = x, lat = y ,color="green", radius = 2, layerId = id, label = id,
                    labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = "bottom",
                     style = list("color" = "green","border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"))
                  ) 
  }) 
  
# Map Click Behaviour -----------------------------------------------------

  #When map is clicked: update map and change dropdown value
  observeEvent(input$region_map_marker_click, {
    
    event <- input$region_map_marker_click

    updateSelectInput(session,
                      inputId = "Site",
                      label = "Pick a site",
                      choices = Site,
                      selected = event$id)

  })
  
  # Update map when a new site is selected from the dropdown
  observeEvent(input$Site, {
    update_markers()
  }) 
  
  
  
  # Function to redraw markers and highlight the selected location
  update_markers <- function(){

    y <- Lat
    x <- Lon
    id <- Site
    sitInd <- id == input$Site
    
    leafletProxy("region_map") %>% clearMarkers() %>% addCircleMarkers(lng = x, lat = y ,color="green", radius = 2, layerId = id, label = id,
                                                                       labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = "bottom",
                                                                                                   style = list("color" = "green","border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")),
                                                                       options = list(zIndex = 200)) %>% 
    addCircleMarkers(lng = x[sitInd], lat = y[sitInd] ,color="blue", radius = 4, layerId = id[sitInd], label = id[sitInd],
                     labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = F, direction = "bottom",
                                                 style = list("color" = "blue","border-color" = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")),
                     options = list(zIndex = 300) )
  }

}
```

Comment: Your plot depends on two input variables, and they won't register a change at the same time. I recommend creating a reactive data block with your `xts(.)` and then using *just* that, [debounced](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/debounce.html), in your `output$region_map`. (I suggest `debounce`ing so that it won't react too quickly.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That sounds like a viable solution, although adding in a delay sounds like a work around not to mention adding time to the visualisation process. I feel like I have misunderstood something about the reactive chain. Its seems like there should be a way to say: if the map is clicked, update the calendar, dropdown and line plot, if the dropdown is selected update the map, calendar and line plot. If the calendar is modified, update the line plot only. It seems to me that this wouldn't be an uncommon thing to do in shiny.